# Who made Medusa's Daughter pregnant?

Tags: kagerou-project

Well... this is awkward:

First we have the literary medusa, Azami, in a nice black dress with red eyes and her partner Tsukihiko.

They have a child. That child's name is Shion, and Shion, half-meduse, half human has a child of her own. That child is Marry...

Now to the interesting part: Who the heck is the father?

I mean, it's kind of difficult to get pregnant in a tower in the middle of the forest on top of a cliff... alone...

Comment: In 4th light novels, we get the story of medusa and Tsukihiko. Shion is mentionned but nothing is told about her. All we know is that she may be related to the kagerou daze world. Also, it is not a tower but a simple house according to the light novel.

Comment: I don't think it's elaborated on, but presumably Shion found herself in a similar situation to her mother: coming across a human man who she fell in love with.